# How does Vue lifecycle works? and use it for skeleton and loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

this question my look silly but i got stuck in this!
i'm using Vuetify skeleton and created a data `isLoading` like the codes bellow. on page refresh every thing is fine but on route change (go back and forward in my pages) it's not working.

in my codes, when page is refreshed `btn` becomes disabled and `mycomponent` show skeleton using the same `isLoading` in its file. but when i go forward and back to it, my btn is loaded, not disabled, mycomponent load after a time without showing skeleton!

what's the problem! i guest it's about using the lifecycle!

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-btn :disabled="isLoading">Button</v-btn>
        <mycomponent />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import mycomponent from '~/components/mycomponent'

export default {
    components:{
        'mycomponent': mycomponent
    },
    data(){
        return{
            isLoading: true
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.isLoading = true
    },
    mounted(){
        this.isLoading = false
    }
}
</script>
```

mycomponent:

```
<template>
    <v-skeleton-loader
    :loading="isLoading"
    type="button"
    width="100%"
    >
        <v-btn>Button</v-btn>
    </v-skeleton-loader>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data(){
        return{
            isLoading: true
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.isLoading = true
    },
    mounted(){
        this.isLoading = false
    }
}
</script>
```

So The Problem: It only works when i land on page for first time or refresh browser. by going forward and back to this page neither `disable button` nor `skeleton on component` works.

**Update**

I'm on NuxtJs v2.13

Answer (score 1):

The `created` hook is called when the vue instance is created and the `mounted` hook is called when the vue instance has been mounted in the DOM. These hooks are called when a component is routed to for the first time or when the page is refreshed. That explains why it only works when you land on the page for the first time or refresh the browser.

When a component has been mounted, pressing the back button on the browser won't call the `created` and `mounted` hook.

To solve your problem, you can watch the `$route` object, by doing

#### App.vue

```js
watch: {
  '$route' () {
     // this will be called any time the route changes
     this.isLoading = true // you can think of a way to make isLoading false
   }
},
```

For more on lifecycle hooks, check out this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/introduction-to-vue-lifecycle-hooks/).

Comment: u sure about your code?? i used watch and wont get anything!! i used `console.log('changed')` and nothing!

Comment: Apologies. I have edited my answer. The watcher should be in `App.vue`. You can use an EventBus to transmit the isLoading state or you can make the isLoading state global in the root vue instance. i.e `new Vue({..})` @MojtabaBarari

Comment: apology is mine! forgot to say i'm on NuxtJs 2.13 . i used an event on `mycomponent` to send `isLoading` when mounted. it works on route change but on first load and refresh the `isLoading` remain true!!

Comment: @MojtabaBarari, have you been able to fix it? If you have, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: no. as i said even emiting event from child component when is `mounted()` and listening on my main component on `created()` not works!

Comment: Hi @MojtabaBarari, have you tried my latest fix? Putting the watcher in the `app.vue` file and firing an eventbus emit from the file to the App.vue.

Comment: Hi @Tony , no , not yet. as i said i'm on nuxtjs. does App.vue work on nuxt too!? if yes, should i create an app.vue file in my pages beside index.vue?